pass CSV file data as an input to hit an API
I have a CSV file in ADLS which contains SerialNumber, 10 000 SerialNumbers. I have a web activity which should hit an API. To hit API, I must pass id, secret, code and the list of SerialNumbers which is in ADLS csv file. How I can optimise this hitting an API?
I tried taking lookup activity followed by append variable inside foreach activity and then a set variable, but it is taking more than 2 hours.

Lookup activity won't support more than 5000 rows and looping all items might not be a better option.
Instead, you can use copy activity to achieve your requirement.
But first, convert your csv file to a Json file using a copy activity (source-csv and sink-Json dataset). Then pass this JSON file to your API. Create a REST linked service with your API as HTTP is not supported as sink.
You mentioned that you need to pass id, secret and code. If those are part of the Authentication, then you can pass those in the REST linked service.

If those need to be dynamic, then you can make use of linked service parameters and dataset parameters to pass those at pipeline level.
Take another copy activity and give the source JSON dataset to this. If you want pass the id, secret and code with your source data then you can pass it using Additonal columns in the copy activity source.

Give the REST dataset as sink. You can also, pass any headers as per your requirement.

Now, debug the pipeline and your source data will be sent to the API. But make sure you pass your id, secret and code in a correct way as per your requirement.
